# ADFS and Native App Authentication with JWT

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, jwt, windows-10-universal, adfs

I obtained a JSON web token from ADFS and called web API functions successfully. It worked. However I cannot covert the code into Windows 10 Native or Universal app.

Anyone knows how to do it? My below code works perfect in a console application.

I don't have any idea how to include `WSTrustChannelFactory` in a native app. In addition, The below (GenericXmlSecurityToken).TokenXml has got an issue as well.

```
var token =  GenericXmlSecurityToken GetJWT();
client2.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.TokenXml.OuterXml);
```

Or better idea for mobile apps?

Thank you

```
private static GenericXmlSecurityToken GetJWT()
{

        //string endpointUri = string.Format("https://{0}/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed", _serverName);
        string endpointUri = string.Format("https://{0}/adfs/services/trust/2005/usernamemixed", _serverName);

        var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(
                      new UserNameWSTrustBinding(),
                      new EndpointAddress(endpointUri));

        //factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;
        factory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrustFeb2005;

        if (factory.Credentials != null)
        {
            factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = _userName;
            factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = _password;
        }

        var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
        {
            RequestType = RequestTypes.Issue,
            KeyType = KeyTypes.Bearer,
            AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(_relyingPartyUri),
            KeySizeInBits = 0,

            TokenType = "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt",

        };

        var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
        try
        {
            var token = channel.Issue(rst);
            return token as GenericXmlSecurityToken;
        }
        catch (ProtocolException ex)
        {
            Debug.Write(ex.Message);
        }
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have any idea how to include WSTrustChannelFactory in a native app

The best practice is avoid placing this method in UWP app, it should be wrapped in a web service and return the security token to our UWP app.

[image]

If you're side-loading (which you don't need to publish to Microsoft Store) then you can look into adding a brokered Windows Runtime Component or a desktop app(Console/Winform/WPF...) as a broker server

See [Brokered Windows Runtime Components for side-loaded Windows Store apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps)

Answer (score 0):

It should be similar to a native WPF application. Instead of using WSTrustChannelFactory, use **ADAL v2.28**.

Set the authority, resourceURI, ClientID, and ReturnURI. Then use them to create an AuthenticationContext and request a token. Finally, stuff the token in the authorization header and send the request to the API.

On the API side manually verify the token and set the ClaimsPrincipal for protected controllers & methods.

When I have a few more minutes, I'll edit this and add some links & sample code. For now, refer to this example.

[ADAL Native Client Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn660969.aspx)